# Fix tag inconsistency for Kingdoms of Amalur

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

We have two tags for this game:

- [kingdoms-amalur-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-amalur-reckoning) for the original 2012 version
- [kingdoms-of-amalur-re-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-of-amalur-re-reckoning) for the remastered 2021 version

I suppose this was due to our old 25 characters limit for tags.
Can we rename it to [kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renamed to [kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning).  Should be good to go!

Comment: So quick and efficient! :D